# How to connect to rabbit on vagrant host?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, vagrant, pika

I set up a server using vagrant on a virtual machine. After installing rabbitmq, I tried to connect to it using script outside VM. There's already Django and RabbitMQ running on VM. After running a script I have an exception:

```py
pika.exceptions.IncompatibleProtocolError: StreamLostError: ('Transport indicated EOF',)
```

How to solve my problem?

My friend already used the code provided below on raspberryPi which actually managed to execute it. The only thing I changed on my PC was the hostname changed from the specified IP to my '127.0.0.1'and I added the port number.

```py
import pika
import sys
import random
import time


credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username='admin', password='admin')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='127.0.0.1',port=15672,credentials=credentials))

channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello',durable=True)
```

Error message:

```
$ python send.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send.py", line 8, in <module>
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='127.0.0.1',port=15672,credentials=credentials))
  File "C:\Users\Pigeonnn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
  File "C:\Users\Pigeonnn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
pika.exceptions.IncompatibleProtocolError: StreamLostError: ('Transport indicated EOF',)
```

Comment: do you forward port `15672` in your Vagrantfile ?

Comment: Yyup I did. But that didnt solve the problem. 
Actually I've just found a solution. The thing is if you want to listen to rabbitmq you need to connect through port 5672 - not 15672. Changed ports, forwarded and everything works :)

Answer (score 4):

@Pigeonnn provided the answer to his own question in [his own comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262829/how-to-connect-to-rabbit-on-vagrant-host/66339416#66339416) to the original question on this very post:

> Actually I've just found a solution. The thing is if you want to
> listen to rabbitmq you need to connect through port 5672 - not 15672.
> Changed ports, forwarded and everything works :)

Answer (score 1):

Stating the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#ports) and highlighting the response, RabbitMQ listening ports are:

```
AMQP:       5672
AMQP/ssl:   5671
HTTP management UI: 15672
```

Answer (score 0):

first forward the a host port to a guest port on Vagrant in the vagrant configuration file (Vagrantfile). Beware to not utilise a host port that is already used.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5672, host: 5671  # Rabbit
end
```

then connect like so:

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username='admin', password='admin')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='127.0.0.1',port=5671,credentials=credentials))
```

don't forget to configure the user admin accordingly.